# Chartjs works fine in localhost but gives error in the server in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I use Bar from "react-chartjs-2" and Chart from "chart.js/auto". They work fine in local development environment but gives error in server. What could cause this and how can I fix that?

My Code:

//BarChart.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";
import Chart from "chart.js/auto";

const BarChart = ({ title, show }) => {
  
  useEffect(() => {
    Chart.register(BarChart);
  });
.......
```

//Home.jsx:

```
import BarChart from "../../components/BarChart/BarChart";
<BarChart
title={"Each Model Name"}
show={data.eachModelCallTimes}
/>
```

The errors:

[image]

Comment: It seems `BarChart` is your chart component; that isn't registrable to  chart.js; you have to register `Bar` and other chart elements you are using, like scales, `Legend`, `Title` and other plugins, but not the chart itself.